# Boost Async Server handling multiple client based on session objects

Tags: c++, networking, boost-asio

I am writing an async server and,  clients who connect to server will request multiple types of data
I mean to say...
Suppose Server is Restaurant here

- Client 1 will connect and request for Pizza, it takes 10 sec to
  respond
- Server will acknowledge the request and has to respond/callback when data[pizza] is ready
- Client 2 will connect and request for Burger, it takes 3 sec to
  respond
- Server will acknowledge the request and has to respond/callback when data[burger] is ready

How can i design this case, or handle it in my server code ???

By the example given in

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/server.cpp

````
new_session = new session(io_service_, context_);
      acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
          boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error)); ```

1) So the multiple clients can be hanlded by multiple session object that are getting created. Is the statement correct ? 
2) Does server will keep each new_session object in a list to differentiate the clients SO that it will respond to them based on the type of request
````

Comment: I'm a little confused. The question's title is about session IDs, which implies multiple requests from single client sharing some server state, but the question's body is about handling concurrent (apparently context-free) requests. Which is it?

Comment: Can you please eloborate, See when the Burger is Ready, Server should respond to Client2 Saying take your burger... @Frank, Corrected the title

Comment: I think I have an example for your use case. Check this
https://github.com/VikashChandola/cpptftp/blob/master/src/tftp_server.cpp#L403
Here code keep on looping between perform_distribution and perform_distribution_cb method. Whenever a new request comes(via a new client) it creates a new job for that and start listening for next job. You can do similar thing for tcp as well. There async_accept will give you a new socket to work on.